# "Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function" while trying to persist some data in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working in a React website and I got this error while trying to make some data persistent in Redux store.
`Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function` 
The thing is, I do not have any function called "e". Here is  the code which I think causes the issue:

```js
import reducer from "../reducer/index"
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return undefined;
  }
};

const saveState = (state) => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return undefined;
  }
};

const enhancers = [loadState(), applyMiddleware(thunk)];
const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  composeEnhancer(...enhancers)
);
 
store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState(store.getState());
});

export default store;
```

Comment: Show the full error stack

Comment: Here is the full error stack from [Firefox](https://pastebin.com/Q6cdzG7j) or from [Chrome](https://pastebin.com/QxN33EaZ)